# Why did Missandei say Dracarys?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In *Game of Thrones S08E04 The Last of the Starks*, Euron

> captures Missandei and brings her to Cersei in chains.

When Dany agrees to a parlay with Cersei, she demands Dany's surrender in exchange for

> Missandei.

Upon refusal, she decides to

> execute Missandei and asks for her final words.

Missandei says "Dracarys". Dany has uttered it many times and I am assuming it means "Breath Fire".

But why did she choose this word. It's a word that means something to Dany but as far as I can tell, no meaning to Missandei or the life she had lead.

What was the meaning of Dracarys as relating to Missandei and why did she choose it?

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say it's a throwback to "burn them all" by Mad King Aerys.

Comment: the seed is strong in that one as well

Comment: Related: [Why did Missandei say that?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/100359/49)

Comment: The last word of her life as a free woman was the word that set her free.

Comment: I took it to mean something along the lines of: "my death will be avenged by dragon fire".

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It means Dragonfire in High Valyrian.

> "So I see. Dracarys?"
>
> All three dragons turned their heads at the sound of that word, and Viserion let loose with a blast of pale gold flame that made Ser Jorah take a hasty step backward. Dany giggled. "Be careful with that word, ser, or they're like to singe your beard off. **It means 'dragonfire' in High Valyrian.** I wanted to choose a command that no one was likely to utter by chance."
> <sub>***ASOS - Daenerys I***</sub>

As to why Missendei chose those words, it would only seem that she threw defiance in Cersei's teeth. "Dragonfire" might be her last words, but they are very likely to be prophetic since Dragonfire would probably be the last thing Cersei ever sees after what She's done. It is a promise of Vengeance.

This is what the actress says [about her last words](https://twitter.com/missnemmanuel/status/1125225712984776704):

[image]

And the Directors have also confirmed it (Tip of the hat to [KharoBangdo](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/15706/kharobangdo)):

Comment: I've also read up that "Dracarys" was the word that freed her from being a slave. And after all this time, she finds herself in chains, at the end of her life. So "Dracarys" was her last word to free her soul after death

Comment: @KharoBangdo Possible, I noted the warcry Targaryen army used in Astapor but edited it out after I found direct confirmation from the actress that she meant it as in a promise of vengeance.

Comment: I'd say classic upset teenager. They lose, they want to see the world burn. ;)

Comment: D&D have confirmed in Inside The Episode that her word was meant for Dany to "Light Them Up" https://youtu.be/u8K9XuPrXko?t=455