# Is Daenerys's decision in Kings Landing consistent with her character arc?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In *Game of Thrones S08E05 The Bells*, when the

> Lannister soldiers drop their weapons & ring the bells indicating
>  their surrender, Daenerys still decides to burn Kings Landing to the
>  ground using Drogon.

A large number of people seem to agree that this is a character assassination on the part of D&D (Dan Weiss & David Benioff). In Inside The Episode, they indicted that Daenerys has made this a personal matter rather than just the business of War.

Right from the beginning of S08, we are shown how nobody in Westeros loves her. Even her advisors serve her out of duty & not love. She loses Jorah & Missandei, her closest friends and now she's all alone.

In E05, she says to Jon as nobody loves her, she will choose fear.

In early seasons, when Daenerys sees the vision in House of the Undying, she's in the throne room with snow falling. Everyone assumed it was snow but now, after seeing Arya's scene at the end, we know it wasn't snow but ash falling. So, it was a prophecy.

In the last episode, we see Daenerys talking about her destiny.

So, is Daenerys's decision to burn down Kings Landing consistent with her character arc right from S01? Or was this character assassination on part of D&D?

Was Daenerys Targeryean the Queen of Ashes all along?

Comment: [This gif will suffice all I gotta say on this matter - "You" refers to D&D](https://i.imgur.com/VdzOjDg.gif)

Comment: I do not think this is a duplicate, the other question is about 'why' she did it, at that moment in time. and I agree with that answer, It is clear (the coin flip quote) the writers wanted to play the mad/fear card in that episode, but overall series charcter consistency is a whole other question altogether with in my opinion a completely different answer. Even the lead-up part of the answer there can be hardly seen as a 'consistency' check, just a tiny justification.

Comment: `Was Daenerys Targeryean the Queen of Ashes all along?` Yes, and no. This is a Schrodinger's conundrum. She always had the potential to be, but didn't live out that potential until she did the thing, [as the Directors mentioned](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/212398/21267).